# ADB freezes on any command

Tags: android, windows, adb

I somehow can't get ADB to work on my windows machine

everytime i try to run `adb devices` or `adb start-server` it freezes and does nothing, it only prints `* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037`

With logging it shows the following:

```
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:54 21236 13536 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:54 21236 13536 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 32.0.0-8006631
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:54 21236 13536 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:54 21236 13536 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:54 21236 13536 adb_client.cpp:351] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:54 21236 13536 adb_client.cpp:160] _adb_connect: host:version
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:56 21236 13536 sysdeps_win32.cpp:1032] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
adb.exe D 02-10 19:06:56 21236 13536 sysdeps_win32.cpp:602] _socket_set_errno: mapping Windows error code 10061 to errno 22
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb D 02-10 19:06:56 22512  1472 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 02-10 19:06:56 22512  1472 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 32.0.0-8006631
adb D 02-10 19:06:56 22512  1472 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb D 02-10 19:06:56 22512  1472 adb_trace.cpp:187]
```

I have adb installed through android studio, but i also tried downloading it manually.
There is also no other program running, which could block the port.

I also tried

- disabling ipv6, cause i read somewhere that this solved the issue.
- running it from a different directory
- run it from windows terminal, powershell, cmd
- run it from an elevated terminal

The weird thing is, it sometimes works when android studio starts, but it will never work from the terminal.

i am really out of ideas, as to why this happens.

UPDATE: it seems to be a version issue, but i still don't know why
the version 29.0.6 seems to be the last working version everything newer has the issues stated above. Funnily enough, 29.0.6 still isn't working if started by android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a program called `ASUS DIPAwayMode`, which somehow prevented adb from properly starting

Answer (score 0):

Most likely again what you encounter is caused by one of the bugs introduced with adb of platform-version 32.0. There were quite a few questions on similar topics on all operating systems used by Android developers.

As at the moment (2022-02-11) there is no newer version of adb versions that fixes this problem the recommended way is to downgrade abd to version 31.0:

These are the download urls at Google for the 31.0.3 version:

- [Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r31.0.3-linux.zip)
- [MacOS](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/e8b2b4cbe47c728c1e54c5f524440b52d4e1a33c.platform-tools_r31.0.3-darwin.zip)
- [Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows.zip)

Comment: im not sure if this is related to a bug in 32.0.0 as it is not working with any version down to 29.0.6. is there anything else that could interfere with adb

Comment: @FelixStumvoll check task manager if there is an ADB process running after adb shows the message "daemon not running; starting now". You need to find out if ADB server is running and adb client can't connect or if the ADB server directly crashes after being started or never starts correctly.

Comment: There is a ADB process running according to the task manager. What is imo weird is, that there is no error message indicating any failure

Comment: @FelixStumvoll You can use process explorer or a similar tool to check if the ADB process has opened TCP 5037. If it has opened the port check your system if there is a firewall or some virus scanner that blocks do munication.

Comment: i checked and it seems adb opened the 5037 port
i also created an explicit firewall rule allowing port 5037 but its still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to kill and restart adb. that's work for me. so you can try out this.
Open Command prompt and go to

android sdk>platform-tools>

`adb kill-server`

press enter

and again

`adb start-server`

press enter

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:5037,reuseaddr,fork TCP:$WSL_HOST_IP:5037` on WSL2 to forward ADB server port to Windows. When I exited from that process, I was able to restart with `adb kill-server && adb -a nodaemon start` inside the WSL bash and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you set the proper path of ADB in windows environment variable explicitly.

Comment: Giving a hint n how or where you can do this, would be very helpful